# Determining the client for OAuth client ID

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

Suppose that I have a web application and a mobile app which consume both API A and API B, which the API is use to access the database to get information. So, in this case the client ID is the web application/mobile app or the API?

```
ClientID ClientName
1        API A
2        API B

ClientID ClientName
1        Mobile App
2        Web App
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign client IDs to the mobile app and the web app. So,

```
ClientID ClientName
1        Mobile App
2        Web App
```